# Initialising data structure at compile time

Tags: c++, c++03

I'm creating some initialised data structures for an embedded application I'm writing, but still at the design stage, wondering how to initialise the various data structures.

In the examples below, the sizes of the arrays will never change, but the contents will during the runtime.

One of the data structures is like this:

```
int id;
int type;
unsigned char data[x]
```

So for example (in C notation)

```
{4,1,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}}
{2,0,{4,2,1}}
{3,2,{9,1,2,9,2}}
etc.. (about 20 other lines)
```

The lengths of the above arrays will never change during the running of the application, but the contents will.

So I thought about a templated class:

```
template<int N>
  class ds
  {
     public: // aggregate class for easy initialisation
     int id;
     int type;
     unsigned char elements[N];
     static int size() { return N; }
  };
```

then you can just do:

```
ds<8> v1 = {4,1,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}}
```

Problem: This isn't easy to pass to methods without those methods being templated as well, and that generates too much code bloat - a copy of the method is created for every unique size. I could work around this by casting it to a similar structure and using an "int elements[1]" to get at the data, but then I wouldn't know the size, and it also seems a nasty way of doing it.

I'd rather not have a function call like "doSomething(v1.id, v1.type, v1.elements, v1.size);

So I've dropped back to the old C way of doing things which seems to work:

```
struct foo
{
   int id;
   int type;
   unsigned char *data;
   int size;
};

unsigned char data[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
foo bar = {4,1,data,sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0])};
```

Which works, and I can pass around the 'foo' structure to any method I choose.

**But it's there a more friendly C++ way of doing this? 
Perhaps a way without having to have 'data' and 'bar' as two separate variables?**

Comment: If size is fixed use std::array instead of C raw arrays. For initialization at compile time you'll need a metaprogram.

Comment: I don't see the point in std::array in this case - I can't pass it to a function without templatizing the function and I'll never be using the STL on it, so the iterators are no use to me. I suppose size() could be useful, but then I have to specifically give a size as well instead of letting the compiler determine the size (which I can retrieve using a sizeof()). So overall it doesn't seem to offer any benefit to me over raw C arrays.

Comment: If I'm not mistaking the C method could lead to some problems where for example if you do this in a function, then `data` would be poped from the stack and the `*data` member of the `bar` variable would be pointing to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Some compilers accept the field name specifier initialization:

```
foo bar =
{
  .id = 4,
  .type = 1,
  .data = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},
  .size = sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]),
};
```

Unfortunately, Visual Studio 2010 still doesn't allow this syntax.

If the data is constant, you may want to prefix the variable as `static const`.  This will allow the linker / compiler to place the data into a read-only section.

Comment: I can't use designated initialisers as the compiler doesn't allow them in C++ mode (not part of the spec), also the data changes at run time like I said in my question so I can't use static const. Also, in C99 mode, the .data assignment doesn't work either - "Error: a value of type "int" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "unsigned char *" whilst parsing ".data = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}". Is this part of the spec?

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler supports C++11, you could use *in class member initialization*. See the following piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo
{ 
  int size = 3;
  int id   = 1;
  int type = 2;
  unsigned char data[3] = {'1', '2', '3'};
};

int main()
{
  foo a;
  std::cout << "a.id    = " << a.id      << std::endl;
  std::cout << "a.size  = " << a.size    << std::endl;
  std::cout << "a.type  = " << a.type    << std::endl;
  std::cout << "data[0] = " << a.data[0] << std::endl;
  std::cout << "data[1] = " << a.data[1] << std::endl;
  std::cout << "data[2] = " << a.data[2] << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Note however, that the initialization is not done during compile time but rather at run-time when the variable `a` is being declared and its constructor is evoked.

I can't see how you could initialize a member variable (i.e., a chunk of memory) during compile time since it's not static (i.e., It's not possible to initialize regular member variables at compile time).

Answer (score 0):

Is there a statement that says you need to create a fixed size data strucuture? I know you said the size will never change so why not use a `vector<unsigned char>`? Or you can mix C with C++ and create a constructor for the struct that allocates the array and copies items over for example:

```
struct foo
{
   foo(int size, char* in_data) {
       data = new char[size];
       memcpy(data, in_data, size * sizeof(char));
   }
   int id;
   int type;
   unsigned char *data;
   int size;
};
```